# How to find a row with a column (DataTypes.ARRAY) that contains in the array a certain value?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sequelize.js, psql

I am developing an application for a restaurant.
They have a PSQL database.
In the Dish model there's the attribute "ingredients" with ARRAY datatype.
I'm trying to build a search bar in the front-end to find in the database, all rows that contain the specified ingredient in the "ingredients" column array.

```
//I know the query below works but have no idea how to implement it (or some other one with same result) in sequelize.js
select * from dishes where'Ingredient'=ANY(ingredients);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code below requires the Operator data from sequelize and the Dish model from the database so we can apply the findAll() method with a clause to search all the dishes matching the data specified with the operator.
>
> The operator to search a value in an array datatype columns in a psql database using sequelize.js is Op.contains as shown in the example below.

```js
 const {Op}=require("sequelize");
 const {Dish}=require("./dbExample);
 
 Dish.findAll({
   where:{ [Op.contains]:["ingredientExample"] }
 }).then((dishes)=>{
   console.log(dishes)
 });
```

> This code logs an array containing the info of every row in the database that matches the searched data.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34484901)